# using the nix typing system with `nix-instantiate`

Tags: nix, nixos

## myservice

i've written a nixos service in `myservice.nix` and i include it in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` with:

```
imports [ /path/to/myservice.nix ];
```

and later i'm using it inside `configuration.nix`:

```
services.myservice.enable = true;
```

## question

in one scenario i can't use `nixos-rebuild switch` but because typing in `nix` is linked to the `options system` using `foo = mkOption { type = types.int; ...}` i'm forced to use the `options systems` even though i just want to compute a configuration file for `nginx` using nix.

**how to evaluate that nginx.conf only?**

@aszlig wrote me this command:

```
nix-instantiate --eval --strict -E '(import <nixpkgs/nixos> { configuration = { imports = [ nixcloud-reverse-proxy/nixcloud-reverse-proxy.nix ]; services.nixcloud-reverse-proxy.enable = true; }; }).config.system.build.configsFromPath'
```

## execution results in

```
nix-instantiate --eval --strict -E '(import <nixpkgs/nixos> { configuration = { imports = [ ./nixcloud-reverse-proxy.nix ]; services.nixcloud-reverse-proxy.enable = true; }; }).config.system.build.configsFromPath'
error: attribute ‘configsFromPath’ missing, at (string):1:1
(use ‘--show-trace’ to show detailed location information)
```

## update

```
nix-build '<nixpkgs/nixos>' -A config.systemd.services.nixcloud-reverse-proxy.runner -I nixos-config=./configuration.nix
...
/nix/store/lp2jbb1wahhlr7qkq81rmfvk84mjk1vk-nixcloud-reverse-proxy-runner
```

now i can use that to grep the conf file:

```
cat /nix/store/lp2jbb1wahhlr7qkq81rmfvk84mjk1vk-nixcloud-reverse-proxy-runner  | grep -o ' /nix/store/.*nginx-reverse-proxy.conf'
```

... kind of a workaround but not very precise! i'd rather like a config file in a directory.

Comment: clever:
nix-build '<nixpkgs/nixos>' -A config.systemd.services.nixcloud-reverse-proxy.runner -I nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your file name is `nginx-reverse-proxy.conf`, so it isn't built with fancy NixOS module system, but with some other ways. In that case (you control how you build your file) you can include it globally:

```
 environment.etc."myconfigs"."nginx-reverse-proxy.conf".text = ...content of that file;
```

Which your refer then with

```
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E '
   with import <nixpkgs/nixos> {
       configuration = { ... };
   };
   config.environment.etc."myconfigs"."nginx-reverse-proxy.conf".text
  '
```

You probably need to decode that output though using trick described in https://gist.github.com/danbst/a9fc068ff26e31d88de9709965daa2bd

which is itself a convoluted way to do

```
$ cat $(nix-build -E '
    with import <nixpkgs/nixos> {
      configuration = { ... };
    };
    config.environment.etc."myconfigs"."nginx-reverse-proxy.conf".source
  ')
```

In case your proxy config is part of general `nginx.conf` script, then you still can get it using

```
$ cat $(cat $(nix-build -E '
     with import <nixpkgs/nixos> {
       configuration = ...;
     };
     config.system.build.units."nginx.service".unit
   ')/nginx.service \
    | grep nginx.conf \
    | sed -r 's/.* (.*nginx.conf).*/\1/g'
  )
```

Because `nginx.conf` file is private to `nginx` module, we can't reference it directly, but have to extract it directly from usage site.

Overall, NixOS lacks a good interface to introspect its internals, but it is still possible.